# Reproject and mosaic MODIS level2 using gdal/python

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, gdal

I have a dataset of MODIS atmospheric products (MOD04) in .hdf format and I want to reproject and save them as Geotiff. I know that it is possible to do it using gdalwarp, but the problem is that I need to do some manipulation before saving the images. Basically, what I need is to read different subdatasets from hdf file, do some modifications using numpy, and finally save the array as a Geotiff file.

I am not expert in using gdal, but I know generally how it works. I must note that when I open MOD04 hdf file by gdal, it seems that gdal is not able to read its GeoProjection and GeoTransform data!

```
>>> src = 'D:/Test/MYD04_L2.A2007231.0745.006.2014054160056.hdf'
>>> dataset = gdal.Open(src,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
>>> print dataset.GetProjection()

>>> print dataset.GetGeoTransform()
(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Above is an example of reading my hdf file. It is the same when I directly open the subdatasets. I am wondering if anyone knows how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your data is already projected, so reprojecting with `gdalwarp` is not going to work. You first need to resample the MODIS Swath data to a grid. You could do this with tools like `MRTSwath` or [PyResample](https://github.com/mraspaud/pyresample/) for example.

Theoretically `gdalwarp` should be able to handle the lat/lon grid as geolocation arrays, but i don't think its working well due to the bow-tie effect of a scanning sensor.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes you are right, my data is not projected but gdalwarp works perfectly on this data and there is no bowtie effect. I just compared the result of gdalwarp with HEGtool and they are almost identical. The problem is that I don't want to project every single subdataset that I need and then do my calculations and save the result. I am looking for a way to read subdatasets as arrays, do my stuff and the project the final array as Geotiff.
Anyway, I will have a look at PyResample and will update the post if I found a solution.